# Pattern matching vs record syntax function for data type field extraction

Tags: haskell

Given an example data type with record syntax:

```
data VmInfo = VmInfo {infoVid   :: String
                     ,infoIndex :: Int
                     ,infoPid   :: Int
                     ,infoExe   :: String
                     } deriving (Show)
```

and (vmInfo :: String -> VmInfo) function that generates and returns the above data structure given vm name as string.

I can see two methods to extract the individual parts of the VmInfo data type.

```
(VmInfo vid _ _ _) <- vmInfo vm
```

Which is just a pattern match. And ...

```
vid <- infoVid <$> vmInfo vm
```

using record syntax compiler generated functions.

The question is simple: which is a preferred  method?

Amount-of-typing wise they are the same so I am looking for speed and correctness/best practice.

I assume the pattern matching would be faster but then what is the point of record syntax?

Comment: I believe the record syntax gets turned into the pattern matching version by the compiler, so there will be no speed difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These aren't semantically equivalent.

Let's look at the first example:

```
(VmInfo vid _ _ _) <- vmInfo vm
```

This performs a pattern match in the binding operation. There are two results of this. The first is that the constructor of the result of the `vmInfo vm` action is evaluated. This means that if `vmInfo` ended with a line like `return undefined`, the exception thrown by evaluating `undefined` would happen at this pattern match, not a later use of `vid`. The second is that if the pattern match is refuted (the pattern match does not match the value), the monad's `fail` instance will be called with the pattern match error text. That's not possible in this case, but it is generally possible when pattern matching a constructor in a bind.

Now, on to the next example:

```
vid <- infoVid <$> vmInfo vm
```

By the definition of `<$>`, this will be entirely lazy in the value returned by the action (not the effects). If `vmInfo` ended with `return undefined`, you wouldn't get the exception from evaluating `undefined` until you did something that used the value of `vid`. Additionally, if `infoVoid` had the ability to throw any exceptions, they wouldn't end up happening until the use of `vid`, best case.

Interestingly enough, these differences are only present in the scope of a monadic bind. If `vmInfo` was pure and you were binding the name `vid` inside a `let` or `where` expression, they would generate identical code.

In that case, which one you would want to use is entirely up to you. Both are idiomatic Haskell. People generally pick whichever looks better in the context they're working in.

The main reasons people use accessor functions is brevity when the record has so many fields a pattern match is huge, and because they are actual functions - they can be passed to any higher-order function their type fits into. You can't pass around pattern matches as a distinct construct.

Comment: Another reason to use accessors over pattern matching is to make the code a little more robust against changing the data structure as the program is maintained. If you change a data structure in almost any way, typically all pattern matches will now fail to compile. If you're only dealing with a small number of fields at a time in a type with many fields, then using accessors means that alterations to the data structure have a good chance of mostly only affecting the places that use the fields you've added/removed/changed.

Comment: @Ben To get the advantages of both, `VmInfo{ infoVid = vid } <- vmInfo vm`.